# How to SUM a column identified by distinct IDs in related table

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

I'm trying to create a measure that summarizes the number of order items from a table containing multiple rows with the same OrderIds.

These are my tables:

[image]

where the tables contain the following:

**DatesTable**

A list of continuous dates

**Orders**

[image]

**Open Orders (Calculated table as per script below)**

[image]

**What I want to calculate:**

For a given date or date span I want to calculate the sum of NumberOfOrderItems for all unique Orders that are open in the given Date span.

E.g:

- 2019-12-01 to 2020-01-03 = 5 (OrderId:1 = 5 items)
- 2020-01-04 to 2020-01-06 = 7 (OrderId:1 = 5 items) + (OrderId:2 = 2 items)
- 2020-01-08 to 2020-01-13 = 2 (OrderId:2 = 2 items)

I believe I need a combination of **CALCULATE**, **SUMX** and **USERELATIONSHIP**, but I have problems putting it all together...

Does anyone know how to construct this measure?

Kind regards,
Peter

Comment: Peter be careful with your model. Are you aware of the side-effects of using bi-directional relationship in a model like yours?

Comment: Thanks, Seymor - it need not be bi-directional. I missed that.